# Parsing XML files in R:Extract dataframe from XML nodeset

Tags: r, xml-parsing, xmlnode

My sample XML

```
- <Inrix responseId="123" statusText="" createdDate="2016-01-29T05:57:00Z">
    - <SegmentSpeedResultSet coverage="255">
        - <SegmentSpeedResults timestamp="2016-01-29T05:56:47Z">
             - <score="10" speed="57" code="4814018">
                    <SubSegment speed="57" offset="0,1753"/>
               </Segment>
             - <score="30" speed="57" code="4814018" cvalue="57">
                    <SubSegment speed="57" offset="0,1753"/>
                    </Segment>
            </SegmentSpeedResults>
         </SegmentSpeedResultSet>
</Inrix>
```

I want to extract the "speed", "code" and "cvalue" for all entries when score is equal to 30. cvalue is present only when score is 30 otherwise it is omitted. Presently my code is

```
input <- xmlParse("20160128-235648.xml")
nodes <- getNodeSet(input,"//Segment[@score='30']")
```

This is creating the XML nodeset "nodes" containing data only when score is 30. It looks like this

```
    [[4584]]
<Segment code="63365958" speed="41" score="30" c-value="0">
  <SubSegment speed="41" offset="0,433"/>
</Segment> 

attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

However, I am not able to convert this XMLnodeset to a dataframe with values of "code", "cvalue", speed". `lapply(nodes, function (x) xmlSApply(x,xmlValue))` is extracting blank vectors from "Subsegment" rather than "Segment".

I also need to store the "timestamp" in "SegmentSpeedResults" as a separate variable.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247451/r-xml-tree-to-dataframe/36247826#36247826 .  Note that you will need xmlAttrs rather than xmlValue.

Comment: Using `sapply(nodes, function (x) xmlSApply(x,xmlAttrs))` extract dataframe from "Subsegment" rather than from "Segment"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing sapply with xAttrs solved my problem of extracting the values under the node "Segment". This worked fine for me

```
nodes <- getNodeSet(input,"//Segment[@score='30']")
all_parameters <- sapply(nodes, xmlAttrs)
```